Mapping List<string> to comma separated string
I have two types. One is an entity and one is a model. The entity has a property called Items which is a string. The model has a property which is also called Items but it is a List<string> of string.
I am using AutoMapper to map this - like this:
CreateMap<Model, Entity>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Items,
               opt => opt.ConvertUsing<List<string>>(new ListToStringValueConverter()));

Here is my ListToStringValueConverter:
public class ListToStringValueConverter : IValueConverter<List<string>, string>
{
    public string Convert(List<string> source, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source != null)
            return string.Join(",", source);

        return string.Empty;
    }
}

However when mapping is done for the entity from the model
entity = _mapper.Map<Entity>(model);

I get the value for entity.Items as
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Why is my converter not converting the ["1","2"] to "1,2" but to
System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]`?
What am I missing or doing wrong?

Why not MapFrom(s=>string.Join(',', source)?

Given the sample classes
class Model
{
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}

class Entity
{
    public string Items { get; set; }
}

Project the members using MapFrom() method:
var list = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
Model model = new Model { Items = list };

var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Model, Entity>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Items, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => string.Join(',', src.Items))));

Mapper mapper = new Mapper(configuration);
Entity entity = mapper.Map<Model, Entity>(model);

Console.WriteLine("Items: " + entity.Items); // "1,2"


